# latex - pass argument with nested values

Tags: nested, latex, parameter-passing

At the moment I have a command which simply takes an argument and does some mathematical operation on it:

```
\newcommand{\gobblenext}[1]{do some math with #1 and display it}
```

Now, in order to upgrade my home-made library, I also need to take into account different cases, when argument #1 is not just simply a single number. What I would need is a command which would deal with passing something more complex consisting of a description of the case and more values.

For instance:

```
    \newcommand{\gobblenext}[1]{
if #1 has a given format R{num1}{num2} -> apply R function on num1 and num2
if #1 has a given format S{num1}{num2} -> apply S function on num1 and num2
else (if #1 is simple number) just do the math as in original function.
}
```

The truth is, that I have no clue what is the best approach. The reason why I cannot simply define three different commands for each case is because \gobblenext is used by other commands, so that I would have to rewrite a big portion of the library. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Example cases include: `\gobblenext{R{10}{20}}`, `\gobblenext{S{-1}{5.2}}`, `\gobblenext{123}`, ... Does it include anything else?

Comment: At the moment I have only three cases that I would like to take into account, but it would be nice to have a flexibility and add more in the future, probably using the same format. I started working around it using stringstrings package but I don't think it is the right approach, it looks a bit messy.